# Single word for a person who is addicted of using internet

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to know a single word for a person who is greatly addicted of using internet. Please don't answer the word *internetmaniac*. I already have this one.

Comment: The word for a person addicted to X is an X *addict*. *Internet maniac*, on the other hand, is not a word anyone ever uses at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the single word you want has't been coined in English, but I can't prove a negative.

Comment: Internetoholic.

Comment: Can one be 'addicted of' something? Are we not 'addicted to' things?